# TCPClient Reconnect to Local Server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

I am using TcpClient to talk to a device that connects directly to the computer's Ethernet connector via a crossover cable.  I connect to the server in the device by calling TcpClient.ConnectAsync and I read data from the device using TcpClient.GetStream().ReadAsync(). It all works well.

Occasionally the device loses power and I need to reconnect.  As soon as the device loses power I get an IOException which I catch and in response I call TcpClient.Close().  I then try to reconnect by creating a new instance of TcpClient and calling TcpClient.ConnectAsync again.  The connection attempt always times out.  I have to restart the program and then I'm able to connect.

The device also has DHCP.  When I connect it to my LAN and use the exact same code, it works. I am able to reconnect after detecting a power loss.

My question is why is this happening and what can be done to fix it.

Comment: try dispose on the tcp connection - just an idea

Comment: Already tried that.  No luck.  Thanks for the suggestion.